# Were those who were not circumcised in the wilderness debarred from celebrating Pesach?

Tags: passover, brit-milah, dor-hamidbar

Were those who were not circumcised in the wilderness debarred from celebrating Pesach? The uncircumcised were not admitted to Passover celebrations—Exodus 13:5 and Joshua 5 seem to indicate that celebration was suspended until they entered the land—but I have seen answers saying that Passover was still celebrated in the wilderness.

Comment: They were disqualified from bringing the Korban Pesach, but they still had to eat matza, tell the story, get rid of chametz, not do work, ....  Basically everything we do today, minus the parts that were instituted later.

Comment: What answers are these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the Passover **sacrifice** with the Passover **festival**.

The Torah calls the Passover sacrifice "**Passover**". As you yourself reference, the uncircumcised were forbidden from bringing the Passover sacrifice, as were their parents.

As a result, we have a tradition that only the first Passover sacrifice was celebrated in the wilderness.

The Torah calls the 7-day Passover festival the "**Festival of Matza**" and the "Spring festival". The commandments related to the Passover festival are independent of circumcision, and include eating no leaven bread - only Matza, retelling the Exodus on the first night and not doing certain types of work - and even less work during the first and last days of the Passover festival.

The Passover festival was celebrated in the wilderness - or at least I am not aware of any tradition - from sources - to the contrary.